# simply loop through posts

Tags: posts

I know this is a really newbie question, but I can't seem to get the loop to pull from the posts. all it is doing is pulling from the page itself.

I made a template and added the loop to it.

```
<?php
if( have_posts() ) {
  while( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

edit: here is all the code: http://pastebin.com/k2rDu53b

Comment: If your code is itself running in the loop, you won't get expected results. Where is this snippet running?

Comment: right after the body, I thought that was the loop, the have_posts...? a little confused. here is all the code:http://pastebin.com/k2rDu53b

Comment: I meant if you were already in the loop, and then you had that code inside there...not what's happening anyway. What is the output you're seeing on the page?

Comment: Just tested this on my local WP install and it's showing me post titles as I'd expect. Is this in your theme folder and is it running as the active theme, or is it being loaded some other way? If it's a theme, do you have a style.css sheet with at least the basic info defined there? http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List

Comment: Why all the header code in the template? Just call `get_header()` instead, if it needs to differ from the main header file, create another eg. `header-two.php` with the code and call that in the template instead, eg. `get_header( 'two' )`

Comment: o! didn't realize you can do two headers. thats awesome. thanks for tip.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because you're on a page, that's only going to display the query for that page. As such, you'd have to create a new query to bring in the posts you want. Replace your loop with this:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
            $post_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php
            }
        }
?>
```

Here some more information on the query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: At the end, you should reset the query with `wp_reset_postdata();` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query